# Where is the location of OSB logs on local server

Tags: osb

I have installed local OSB 12c _ Integrated Server in Windows 10. I have put some logs in a pipeline:

[image]

which runs without problems:

The Log component is configured as follows:

[image]

But I can not find where to see this log, I'm not even sure if he's registering.

According to the documentation, it should be at: DOMAIN_HOME//domain//servers// server_name//logs//server_name.log
But I can not find this address on my computer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found where the logs are, if someone asks you how to do them, well:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
Hopefully it will be useful to someone

Comment: I had seen the folder location in JDeveloper. However, the log actions from the pipeline aren't showing up in the log.

Comment: Probablly is the level of the log

Comment: Checked the level. It is set to Debug and is on. For some reason, the log component that I insert into the pipeline only works if I set the severity to Warning. Ah well.